# In R, how to use a "null" default value for an argument of a function?

Tags: r, default-value

Here is my current code:

```
my.function <- function( my.arg="" ){
  if(my.arg == "")
    my.arg <- rnorm(10)
  return( mean(my.arg) )
}
```

It returns me this:

```
> my.function( rbinom(10, 100, 0.2) )
[1] 18.5
Warning message:
In if (a == "") a <- rnorm(10) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I tried with `my.arg=c()`, or `my.arg=0`, but I always get either a warning or an error. And the R manual doesn't say much on this issue.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to return the mean value of an arbitrary distribution, and if you don't pass it a distribution and appropriate parameters?, you want to return the mean of `rnorm(10)`?

Comment: @Chase yes, but it's just a dummy example, my "real" function is more complicated... Karsten's solution works.

Comment: What would you expect from `my.function( NA )`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try

```
my.function <- function( my.arg=NULL ){
 if(is.null(my.arg)) ...
```

Answer (score 11):

There's also `missing`:

```
my.function <- function(my.arg) {
  if(missing(my.arg)) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Karsten's approach is correct. The reason for the warning is that you're testing my.arg against "" which is a character vector of length 1, thus the warning when my.arg is a vector of length > 1.
If you really wanted to test whether my.arg is "" you'd need to do something like

```
if (length(my.arg) == 1 && my.arg == "")
```