# How can I specify an argument object when the default is NULL in R?

Tags: r, function, null, default-value

I am trying to write a function that sets the default for some arguments to NULL. However, when I then want to specify those arguments to not be NULL when calling the function, I receive the error that those objects cannot be found.

Simple starter function:

```
library(dplyr)
toydf <- data.frame(Name = "Fred", Age="Old", Hair="Brown")
toyA <- function(df, groupA){
  data.frame(A = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupA}}))
}
toyA(toydf, Name)
toyA(toydf, Age)
```

I want to specify some arguments to have a NULL default, which [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370249/correct-way-to-specifiy-optional-arguments-in-r-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553059/in-r-how-to-use-a-null-default-value-for-an-argument-of-a-function?rq=3) seem to suggest should work. I try this:

```
toyB <- function(df, groupA, groupB=NULL, groupC=NULL){
  if((!is.null(groupB)) & (!is.null(groupC))){
    data.frame(A = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupA}}),
               B = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupB}}),
               C = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupC}}))
  }
  else{
    data.frame(A = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupA}}))
  }
}
```

But this throws me the error:

```
toyB(toydf, Name, Age, Hair)
Error in toyB(toydf, Name, Age, Hair) : object 'Age' not found
```

We can work around it by checking `missing()` as some other questions and solutions suggest.

```
toyC <- function(df, groupA, groupB, groupC){
  if((!missing(groupB)) & (!missing(groupC))){
    data.frame(A = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupA}}),
               B = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupB}}),
               C = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupC}}))
  }
  else{
    data.frame(A = df%>%dplyr::select({{groupA}}))
  }
}
toyC(toydf,Name)
toyC(toydf, Name, Age, Hair)
```

Why is it that the NULL default is not working?

Comment: Haven't opened R to test so this is a comment, but pretty sure it's a non-standard evaluation thing. You {{}} the arguments inside select but can't when checking is.null, so R tries to check `is.null(groupB)`, which resolves to `is.null(Age)`, and then can't find an object `Age` to check (because it's a column of the dataframe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007842/check-if-a-tidyselect-is-null-and-if-so-set-a-default-tidyselect-method. When you check `is.null(GroupB)` you are evaluating the promise that points to `Age` and that variable doesn't exist at the time you are checking `is.null`, it only exists in the data.frame. The dup shows you how to avoid the early evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

You should directly use the NSE within `select`.

```
toyB <- function(df, groupA, groupB=NULL, groupC=NULL){
  df %>% select({{groupA}}, {{groupB}}, {{groupC}})
}

toyB(head(iris), Species)
  Species
1  setosa
2  setosa
3  setosa
4  setosa
5  setosa
6  setosa

toyB(head(iris), Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1  setosa          5.1         3.5
2  setosa          4.9         3.0
3  setosa          4.7         3.2
4  setosa          4.6         3.1
5  setosa          5.0         3.6
6  setosa          5.4         3.9
```

Comment: I would imagine the OP is doing more with these variables, but if all they were doing was simply selecting then they could do: `toyB <- function(df, ...) df %>% select(...)`

Comment: `toyB <- \(df, ...)  df[sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)]` might be more efficient.

Comment: @jay.sf It all depends as to whether OP is interested in using the variable names again. If not needed then even `toyB <- \(df, ...)  df[as.character(substitute(...()))]` should work

Comment: @Onyambu Even more efficient, true.

Comment: My post was not clear as to my real needs. I was primarily trying to figure out how to properly check if the arguments were null. It was not about actually selecting the columns. I believe MrFlick's linked question under my post is what I need.